# how to place a kendo check box label on the left

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, label, checkboxfor

I have the following peace of code:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive).Label("Active:"))
```

I would like the label to be on the left as opposed to the right. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot be done using the Html helper alone since it always places it on the right. As stated in this link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/checkbox-label-before-checkbox-input

> The Kendo UI checkbox styling requires the rendering to have first the
>   checkbox, then the label tag, so that the latter can be styled, based
>   on the checkbox state

To get it on the left, you can omit the label from the helper and add the labelling element to your page separately before it, for example:

```
<label for="@Model.IsActive">Active:</label>
@(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive))
```